# Mysql left outer join with a column in right table that is not foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

My understanding of left outer join is,

```
table1:
id(pk) name(unique_key) address phone

table2:
    new_id(pk) name(foreign key) company work-experience

1st table:
1 a x 123
2 b y 234
3 c z 345

2nd table
1 a aaa 2
2 a aab 3
3 b aab 3
```

if I will do,

```
select * from table1 left outer join table2 on table1.name=table2.name,

it will give me
1 a x 123 1 a aaa 2
1 a x 123 2 a aab 3
2 b y 345 3 b aab 3
3 c z 345 NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

Now instead of above result, I want to get all the rows where company is aab. Also , for any entry in 1st table, if there is no corresponding entry in 2nd table then it should give me NULL for all columns in 2nd table.

like this:

```
1 a x 123 aab 3
2 b y 234 aab 3
3 c z 345 NULL NULL
```

is the above result possible with left outer join ? If not, How can I get the above result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the conditions for the second table (right-side table), in the `ON` part of `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2
  ON t1.name = t2.name AND 
     t2.company = 'aab'
```

Also, in case of multi-table queries, it is advisable to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/), for code clarity (enhanced readability), and avoiding unambiguous behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`select t1.name,t1.address,t1.phoneNo,t2.comapnay,t2.workExperiance from table1 as t1
left outer join table2 as t2 on t1.name=t2.name AND 
                          t2.company = 'aab'`